# The prefix "atom" for element "atom:cc" is not bound exception

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts

I am trying to fetch the contacts of the user who have an account in google apps marketplace. While fetching the contact i get the following error

```
  com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: The prefix "atom" for element "atom:cc" is not bound.      
  at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:695)|
  at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:568)|
  at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(BaseFeed.java:793)|
  at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:68)|
  at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)|
  at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.CharacterParser.parse(CharacterParser.java:)|
  at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.XmlInputParser.parse(XmlInputParser.java:52)|...
```

I am using Java client library to fetch the contacts. Can you please let me know is there an issue in the java client library? This issue is there for a long time and I badly need to find a solution for this...What should I do to make it work...Any help will be grateful..

Thanks,
VijayRaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same Problem, that you have with the Java Client, with the .NET client.

After contacting Google support, they told me that the Contacts arbitrary XML data which is in an Property element cannot be parsed within my version of GData .

However, there is a time intensive workaround, by deleting and recreating Contacts, but thats probably not what you are looking for, me either.

After switching to the Python implementation all works fine now.

Check out this Issue report [Issue 361](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=361)